# Is mixed slugs (numbers & names) in WordPress a bad SEO technique?

Tags: wordpress, seo, slug

While trying to get friendly urls in WordPress I jumped into this http://wordpress.org/support/topic/duplicate-category-slugs-desperately-needed-will-this-ever-be-fixed

So the question is, how bad is from the SEO point of view to use something like this...

```
mysite.com/cars/1-honda    
mysite.com/trucks/2-honda    
mysite.com/motors/3-honda
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Answer (score 1):

No one can really answer your question, because Google doesn't publish much about how PageRank works, and for good reason.

That being said, I don't see why something like that would be a problem. It still incorporates the keywords you're trying to use into the URL, and the superfluous number isn't likely to detract from that; many websites put numbers in URLs for internal purposes. While it arguably distracts from the human aesthetics of the URL, I think you're worrying about nothing when it comes to SEO.

Comment: So would you recommend using this... mysite.com/cars/1-honda or this.. mysite.com/cars/car-honda

Comment: I don't think it makes an significant difference either way.

Answer (score 0):

The numbers won't hurt you as far as SEO